# Django can not show image in folder

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I create folder images path **static/media/images/** and upload image 02.jpg to folder images by FTP. I want to show image 02.jpg to index.html but it's not show image. This is my code.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns+=static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns+=static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
#BASE_DIR is project location
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')
```

**index.html**

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static '/images/02.jpg' %}" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: what is the value of `src` when you rightclick on the `img` and inspect the element?

Comment: Try changing the `img` tag in `index.html` to `<img src="{% static 'media/image/02.jpg' class="d-block w-100" alt="">`

Answer (score 0):

Now I can fix it by using.

```
<img src="/media/images/02.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
```